# Will legitimate email ever be sent TO mailer-daemon@?

Tags: email, requirements

I seem to be getting a rash of spam addressed to mailer-daemon@ my domain. I also get a lot of spam to postmaster@ and I live with that because RFC 5321 requires that to be a valid address. But does mailer-daemon@ need to accept mail?

Legitimate bounce messages come *from* mailer-daemon@ so I don't want to block based on sender address, but I was wondering if it's OK to block based on recipient address.

Is there any requirement to accept mail sent ***to*** mailer-daemon@? Will legitimate mail ever be sent ***to*** mailer-daemon@?

I didn't see mailer-daemon@ mentioned in RFC 5321. My search attempts showed lots of results for messages ***from*** mailer-daemon@, but nothing about messages ***to*** mailer-daemon@.

Oh and if I block mail to mailer-daemon@, should I just discard it instead of rejecting it? Will rejecting it cause a loop?

Comment: off topic on stackoverflow. short answer: no, mailer-daemon@ does not have to accept mail and you can reject mails to that address. btw: the mailer-daemon thing in legitimate bounces should only be visible in the "from: "-header, but the envelope sender address should be empty.

Comment: @Gryphius I've found myself coming back to this question and found some related info on it. I'd like to post an answer, but not if it's off topic. Which site should I post it to? Would Server Fault be appropriate?

Comment: Server Fault would be more appropriate for this type of question, but since it's already here on SOF you can add the answer here too for googleability.